# why windows registry batfile shell key overwrites value during bootup [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell]

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, windows-registry

I am given a new windows10 Enterprise (20H2) HP laptop for my new job.

When system boot-up, everytime it sets following registry value:

[image]

When this key is set to "edit" as shown above, files with .bat extension opens with notepad.

If I unset this key value ( Removing "edit" ), .bat files can be executed normally:

[image]

But if I reboot my laptop, this value ( "edit" ) comes back again. So I can't unset this value ( "edit") persistently.
There is no program in the %appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup directory

- How can I find which program or OS setting is setting this value to "edit" during bootup ?
- Is there a way to set this value persistently ?

Comment: I remember that MS introduced protections against directly changing file associations by editing the Registry. I would assume that these protections are causing the reset.

Comment: Have you asked your employer IT?

Comment: Yes, sadly they also don't know. This is quite weird, I wonder if this only happens for me or is it a new policy of new win10 ? I will ask other colleagues as well, to check if they have the same issue or not. Thank for the answer.

Comment: Ask them to set up your computer again.

Comment: You can run Process Monitor from MS's Sysinternals collection of utilities to find out which process is changing thos registry values. It can be set to run at next boot, and filter results based on registry path.

Comment: Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your IT department.

Comment: To understand this, the Process Monitor from boot option is the correct one, you will see the process that changes the reg value.  You can see the stack of this registry event to see the module making the registry API call.  With Symbols configured, it's likely to reveal the cause.

Comment: Ok, this gets more complicated that I expected. But thanks for the suggestion, I will take a look at Process Monitor. I assume you are referring to this : https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/process-monitor-track-events-generate-log-file/